# Modular Android Applications

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application which needs to be dynamic depending on a users account settings in a separate web application.

Are there development techniques, patterns etc which are alternatives to simply using an abundance of "if" statements to handle enabled features?

For example, subsidiaries are a feature. If this is enabled, then this affects the workflow of the application. However if this is not enabled that application needs to work differently.

I understand that this question is extremely broad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create two classes instead of each "if" - one with empty methods, another with actual functionality, derived from the first one, then create an instance of the appropriate class depending on your settings during app start, so you will have only one "if" for each setting in your init code.

Comment: @pelya Thanks for that. I should have explained that under one Activity, there can be any combination of, say, 5 features that are enabled and they can affect each other. How would you approach this?

Comment: Then you have tightly-coupled functionality, which you cannot split into independent parts, so your code will be ugly in one way or another, no matter which approach you will choose. Try to de-couple functionality, maybe move some less-used feature into a separate Activity, if it's possible.